# cannot locate files in docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker compose to create an image. when run my docker image throws an exception saying server.py not found. Any help would be appreciated.

below is the snippet of my docker-compose file

```
version: '2'
```

services:

```
python:
    build: .
    image: python:3.6
    environment:
        DEBUG: 'true'
        PORT: '8080'
volumes:
        - ./:/web/server       
links:
        - postgres
    ports:
        - "8080:8080"
    command: ["python", "server.py"]

postgres:
    image: onjin/alpine-postgres:9.5
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
        - "5442:5432"
    environment:
        LC_ALL: C.UTF-8
        POSTGRES_USER: ahmad
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ahmad
        POSTGRES_DB: ahmad
```

Dockerfile snippet

```
ENV DIR /web/server
ADD . ${DIR}
WORKDIR ${DIR}
```

Comment: i cant see where you include dockerfile into docker-compose, if you want to executer commands from dockerfile in docker-compose you need to include it like this `build: ./folder_which_contains_dockerfile`

Comment: I have updated the compose file as shown below. docker file is placed in the current directory. I still get the same error.

 python:
        build: .
        image: python:3.6
        environment:
            DEBUG: 'true'
            PORT: '8080'
        volumes:
            - ./:/server/http
        links:
            - postgres
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        command: ["python", "recipe_server.py"]

Comment: did you post full docker-compose.yml?

Comment: No it was just the python image part. I have updated the file above

Comment: I found this server.py files in your docker container
`/usr/local/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/server.py

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/server.py

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bzrlib/smart/server.py

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mercurial/hgweb/server.py`

which one you need?

Comment: python3.6/http/server.py. how did you find that?

Comment: Create dockerfile with python image, that you specify in your dockerfile, as entrypoint set bash, after it run container, type cd, and then type find . -name "server.py"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:

  python:
      build: ./folder_with_docker_file
      command: ["python", "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/http/server.py"]
      volumes:
        - ./:/web/server       
      links:
        - postgres
      ports:
        - "8080:8080"
      environment:
          DEBUG: 'true'
          PORT: '8080'

  postgres:
      image: onjin/alpine-postgres:9.5
      restart: unless-stopped
      ports:
          - "5442:5432"
      environment:
          LC_ALL: C.UTF-8
          POSTGRES_USER: ahmad
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ahmad
          POSTGRES_DB: ahmad
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV DIR /web/server
ADD . ${DIR}
WORKDIR ${DIR}
```

Structure:

```
├───stack
│   │   docker-compose.yml
│   │
│   └───test
│           dockerfile
```

stack and test is folders